# Prove that $||x+y|| \leq ||x|| +||y||$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, normed-spaces

From Munkres' Topology, I get this question. A hint suggests us to use a result from a previous subquestion. But it seems that I don't need to use the previous result to prove this. Can someone help me to see if I can do that? The picture is the exercise that I'm working on. Following that is a proof for $(c)$.
[image]

Proof：
$$\begin{align*}
||x+y||^2 &= (x+y)(x+y)\\
&=(x+y)x+(x+y)y\\
&=xx+yx+xy+yy\\
&=||x||^2+2(xy)+||y||^2\\
& \leq ||x||^2+2||x||||y||+||y||^2\\
&=(||x||+||y||)^2.
\end{align*}$$
Since $||x+y||$ and $(||x||+||y||)$ in the set of nonnegative real numbers, we have 
$$||x+y||\leq||x||+||y||.$$

Comment: Yep (once you fix the squaring).  As appears in innumerable books and online.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork But why did Munkres give a hint to use the result $(b)$? What's his intention?

Comment: Since $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are not single numbers, you need to use the dot product in the expressions, and then you would be using (b) in the inequality from line 4 to line 5.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @user398843, you used (b) in going from the fourth to the fifth line (where the $\le$ sign appears).

Comment: Thank you all. For a more detailed proof, I can write $\leq ||x||^2 + 2|xy| +||y||^2$ between line 4 and line 5. Then apply result $(b)$ to get the fifth line. :)